# Download multiple files as a zip folder using php

Tags: php, zip

I want to make my user select any type of files listed and make them as a zip folder and download it. The files may be .doc,.jpeg,.ppt, etc

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can take a look at [`ZipArchive`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.zip.php), you would be able to create zips with that and let the user download it.

Cletus provide a really good answer [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1754352/download-multiple-files-as-zip-in-php). I humbly copy his sample here

```
$files = array('readme.txt', 'test.html', 'image.gif');
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$zip->open('file.zip', ZipArchive::CREATE);
foreach ($files as $file) {
  $zip->addFile($file);
}
$zip->close();
```

and to stream it:

```
header('Content-Type: application/zip');
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=filename.zip');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($zipfilename));
readfile($zipname);
```

Comment: ok ragez i ll give a try

Comment: class ZipFile not found... I got this error