# How can I zip a directory on the fly and download it?

Tags: php, directory, zip

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Download multiple files as a zip folder using php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1760975/download-multiple-files-as-a-zip-folder-using-php)

Hi, I need a script which would compress current directory and all its files into a zip file and the user would get the download prompt box. I've tried to use [This script](http://solomongaby.users.phpclasses.org/package/2322-PHP-Create-ZIP-file-archives-and-serve-for-download.html) but it says the file size is too big even when I change max file size. Please be specific with the answer because. And yes I used google.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Download multiple files as a zip folder using php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1760975/download-multiple-files-as-a-zip-folder-using-php) and a couple others: [http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=zip+download+php](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=zip+download+php). Please point out why none of these helped solve your questions (as was suggested in [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice))