# How to put many files in one ZIP in PHP?

Tags: php, zip

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Download multiple files as a zip folder using php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1760975/download-multiple-files-as-a-zip-folder-using-php)

Hi everyone,
I have 5 images : image_1.png, image_2.png, image_3.png, image_4.png, image_5.png
HOW can I put all these files in one ZIP file and allow them to be downloded. am in PHP/HTML

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1760975/download-multiple-files-as-a-zip-folder-using-php

Answer (score 0):

In one zip file with PHP? Then you can use this:

http://www.phpconcept.net/pclzip/

It is a really great library, and I used it a few times. Take a look into PclZip how to use it. If you have questions, ask ...