# Application Folder backup using Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, backup

I am trying to create a web app using codeigniter which will be used over a home or office network. Now Im looking for a backup option which can be done from the web protal. For example, in my htdocs folder i have: App1, App2 etc.
i want to backup and download the App1 folder directly from the webapp which can be done from any client machine which is connected to the server. is it possible. if yes then can you please let me know how?
~muttalebm

Answer (score 1):

Basically what you want to do is zip the application folder and download it, fairly simple to do. Please check out:

- [Download multiple files as a zip folder using php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1760975/download-multiple-files-as-a-zip-folder-using-php)

On how to zip a folder for download.

I you do not have that extension a simple command can be used instead, I assume you are running on Linux if not replace command with zip/rar Windows equivalent:

```
$application_path = 'your full path to app folder without trailing slash';
exec('tar -pczf backup.tar.gz ' . $application_path . '/*');
header('Content-Type: application/tar');
readfile('backup.tar.gz');
```

**Note: Make every effort to protect this file from being accessed by unauthorized users otherwise a malicious user will have a copy of your site code including config details.**

Answer (score 1):

sorry for the late reply. I found a quite easy and simple backup option builtin with codeigniter.  Hope this helps someone

```
$this->load->library('zip');
$path='C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\CodeIgniter\\';
$this->zip->read_dir($path); 
$this->zip->download('my_backup.zip');
```

i used the code directly from the view and then just called it using the controller.

~muttalebm

Answer (score 0):

```
// to intialize the path split the real path by dot .
public function init_path($string){
    $array_path =  explode('.', $string);
    $realpath  = ''; 
    foreach ($array_path as $p)
    {

        $realpath .= $p;
        $realpath .= '/';
    }
    return $realpath;

}

// backup files function       
public function archive_folder($source = '' , $zip_name ='' , $save_dir = '' , $download = false){
    // Get real path for our folder
    $name = 'jpl';
    if($zip_name == '')
    {
        $zip_name = $name."___(".date('H-i-s')."_".date('d-m-Y').")__".rand(1,11111111).".zip";
    }
    $realpath  = $this->init_path($source); 
    if($save_dir != '')
    {
        $save_dir = $this->init_path($save_dir); 

    }else{
        if (!is_dir('archives/'))
    mkdir('archives/', 0777);
        $save_dir = $this->init_path('archives'); 
    }

        $rootPath =  realpath( $realpath);
      //  echo $rootPath;
      //  return;

        // Initialize archive object
        $zip = new ZipArchive();
        $zip->open($save_dir . '\\' . $zip_name, ZipArchive::CREATE | ZipArchive::OVERWRITE);

        // Create recursive directory iterator
        /** @var SplFileInfo[] $files */
        $files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
            new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($rootPath),
            RecursiveIteratorIterator::LEAVES_ONLY
        );

        foreach ($files as $name => $file)
        {
            // Skip directories (they would be added automatically)
            if (!$file->isDir())
            {
                // Get real and relative path for current file
                $filePath = $file->getRealPath();
                $relativePath = substr($filePath, strlen($rootPath) + 1);

                // Add current file to archive
                $zip->addFile($filePath, $relativePath);
            }
        }

        // Zip archive will be created only after closing object
        $zip->close();
        if($download){
        $this->download($zip);
        }
}
```

Comment: explain details of the answer here if you really want to help to solve the question.

Comment: the function archive_folder is take a the folder path who want to archive for example if you want archive the controller file in your project call to function $this->archive_folder('application.controllers');

Comment: by default this function save the archived folder in the folder named archives in the behind application folder