# Downloading multiple files as zip

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have this ecommerce site that deals with digital downloads, but the user has to download items one at a time. How could i let them add various items to a cart then let them download the items they chose as one zip? is that possible?

Thanks, 
Ja art

Comment: See this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1754352/download-multiple-files-as-zip-in-php?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's Possible With [`ZipArchive`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.ziparchive.php) class to create a ZIP file.

```
$files = array('file1.pdf', 'file2.doc', 'file3.flv');
$zipname = 'file.zip';
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$zip->open($zipname, ZipArchive::CREATE);
foreach ($files as $file) {
  $zip->addFile($file);
}
$zip->close();
```

To stream it:

```
header('Content-Type: application/zip');
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=filename.zip');
header('Content-Length:'.filesize($zipname));
readfile($zipname);
```

Comment: Thank you bro. Well i'm not really great at coding so how would i impliment this to the site? I'm using wix by the way

Comment: @user3075447 You're Welcome..I think you've to check the basics of eCommerce site to implement your requirement. Thanks..:)