# Save txt file in specific location

Tags: php, jquery, file-upload

I have a recursive function which generates about 200.txt files. I am running this application on a local server.

Basically, the front end just has a file upload field, which you just choose a .csv, which it then generates all the .txt files from that, but rather than saving them on the wamp server, is it possible to save them in a specific location?

Example, if I put another field in my front end called 'fileLocation', and the user types in the pathname.

Obviously i'd have to check if it's a directory etc, but is this possible to say save all the files on:

```
/Volumes/computer/Users/username/Desktop/test/
```

I'm not sure where to proceed with this.

Answer (score 0):

No, is not possible to access computer files this way by using a localhost. You could zip all files and make the browser download them. Like is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1754352/download-multiple-files-as-zip-in-php)

Comment: Yeah, had that idea too, might have to do it that way or just save them recursively into the project directory lol