# How to force-downloads in PHP?

Tags: php, force-download

How do I force-download for multiple links? If user clicks link1 they download pdf1.pdf. If user clicks link2 they download pdf2.pdf. Is there a way to check which link they clicked on?

Comment: `<a href='pdf1.pdf'>link1</a>` and the same for link2?

Comment: I think you zip file and download.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1754352/download-multiple-files-as-zip-in-php

Comment: lookup <a href> on Google. This is basic HTMl, nothing to do with PHP

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I force-download different .pdfs in same script?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28146669/how-do-i-force-download-different-pdfs-in-same-script)

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
<?php
$FileName = 'file.pdf';
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename="'.$FileName.'"');
readfile($FileName);
```

Comment: If I try doing that and I have
$FileName = 'file1.pdf';
$FileName = 'file2.pdf';
It keeps bringing back file1.pdf and not file2.pdf

Answer (score 0):

```
$file_url = 'your_file.someting';
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary"); 
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . basename($file_url) . "\""); 
readfile($file_url);
```

P.S. use proper content-type for your file e.g `application/zip` for `ZIP` files