# PHP zip all image in specific file and generate a download link

Tags: php, zip

I was searching for this but i can't find anything like this.I'm new to PHP, I want to have a backup of all my pictures in specific directory.
I want when i click on link it collect all the images in that directory and compress them into a zip file, then it give me a download link for them.
I saw an answer before for how to (download multiple files as zip in PHP) but i don't know how to get all the images full names in this directory and merge them with the commands for zipping 
 I wish that's possible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [download multiple files as zip in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1754352/download-multiple-files-as-zip-in-php) and others, so i don't know what you searched for.

Comment: no this is not what i mean

Comment: You don't want to zip up some images then push them to download?