# Download button in Laravel with multiple documents ID's on button

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

My query return results from database as comma separated values: `1,2,3..etc`
Then I'm trying to make a button for download and should select 1 or more documents to download ( based on if is 1 id or multiple ).

So button with one file looks like this

```
<a href="users/files/download/2?_token=SivFIl3kKuflAvIyYJFGKdovJHTlqpjObN2nMFbQ">Download Now</a>
```

and button where the query return multiple id's looks like this ( notice the `2,3` before the token )

```
<a href="users/files/download/2,3?_token=SivFIl3kKuflAvIyYJFGKdovJHTlqpjObN2nMFbQ">Download Now</a>
```

This I add to the routes.php

```
Route::get('/users/files/download/{fileId}', 'UsersController@getDownload');
```

And this to the controller

```
public function getDownload($fileId)
{
    $file = Documents::findOrFail($fileId);
    $file = public_path(). "/uploads/" . $file->document_path;
    return Response::download($file, 'filename.pdf');
}
```

Currently no matter which button I click I've got

Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException: No query results for model [Documents].

What is this means? The model is there. This is the Documents model

```
class Documents extends Eloquent
{
    protected $table = 'documents';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    public $timestamps = false;
}
```

And how I can select all documents ID's when they are multiple?

Update: current code

```
$file = Documents::findOrFail([$fileId]);

$zip = new ZipArchive();
$zip_name = time().".zip"; // Zip name
$zip->open($zip_name,  ZipArchive::CREATE);
    foreach ($file as $files) {
    $path = public_path(). "/uploads/" . $files['document_path'];

        if(file_exists($path)){
            $zip->addFromString(basename($path),  file_get_contents($path));
        }
        else{ echo"file does not exist"; }                  
    }
 $zip->close();
```

Comment: it is not possible to download multiple files at a time in laravel, but you can create a zip file of those files and download it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the `$fileId` within an array for more than one id

```
$file = Documents::findOrFail([$fileId]);
$number_of_files = count($file);
if ($number_of_files > 1) {
    // Push all the files in a zip and send the zip as download
} else {
   // Send the file as a download
   $file = public_path(). "/uploads/" . $file->document_path;
   return Response::download($file, 'filename.pdf');
}
```

Comment: Hm, now I get `ErrorException: Undefined index: document_path`. If I `dd($file)` I see that document_path exist

Comment: Probably you are getting more than one result. In that case you need to loop through `$file`

Comment: Yes, I get 1+ result because the ID's are 1+. Loop where? Inside the controller and how to pass it for download then?

Comment: I've added a loop but is downloading only 1 file instead of multiple

Comment: This may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36675505/laravel-5-multiple-download-file

Comment: Okay, got it to download the zip but is always with one file inside

Comment: You need to check the count of results and if there is more than one then use zip else download the file directly

Comment: Thanks. Can you give me simple example of that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149545/discussion-between-linktoahref-and-user5996816).