# Laravel response()->download() issue for multiple images

Tags: laravel

I need to download multiple images using download and return response with some other data. Single image return response is working but when we pass array then return error.

```
return response()->download(['image1.jpg','image2.jpg']);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel 5 Multiple Download File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36675505/laravel-5-multiple-download-file)

Comment: I need without zip file

Comment: Then do 2 requests. each to download a file

Comment: if you have static assets then you can create image sprite, otherwise make multiple requests to download multiple images.