# how to download multiple files from a single cell in sql database? I am using laravel 5.5

Tags: php, sql, laravel, explode

I have a user row with employee's details and $image has multiple files stored in database. I want to download each file. so far I can only download a single file stored in $image

here is `myview.blade.php`

```php
<input type="file" name="image[]" class="form-control" value="{{ $employee['image'] }}" multiple>
 <a href="{{ url('/people/employees/download/' . $employee['image']) }}">{{$employee['image']}}</a>
```

my `route.php`

```php
Route::get('/people/employees/upload/{id}', 'EmplController@upload');
Route::get('/people/employees/download/{image}', 'EmplController@download');
```

my `controller.php`

```php
public function test(Request $request, $id) {
    
    $employee = User::find($id);

    if($request->hasfile('image')){
        $files = [];
        foreach ($request->image as $image) {
            $path = $image->getClientOriginalName();
            $filename = time() . '-' . $path;
            $files[] = $filename;
            $image->storeAs('employees', $employee->id . '/' . $filename);
            $image->move(public_path('employees'),$filename);
        }

        $files = explode(",", $files[0]);
    }

    $employee->image = $employee->image  .  $files[0];
    $employee->save();  
}

public function download($image){
    $employee = User::find($image);
    $filename = $image;
    $filepath = public_path('employees/' . $filename);

    return response()->download($filepath);
}
```

when I do a print_r function while uploading multiple files it picks one file?

```
Array ( [0] => 1596838646-logo.jpg )
```

I want to download multiple files displayed on  myview.blade.

Comment: The `test function` is for update data or get data?

Comment: Is to upload files@sta

Answer (score 0):

I believe that what you asking is to download multiple files over the same request using HTTP protocol and that is not possible as it is explained in this answer:

[Laravel Download Multiple Files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36675505/laravel-5-multiple-download-file)

What I would suggest is to make a client-side function that can make multiple calls to the download method for each specific file.

E.g based on your question, It could be something like:

HTML:

```
<a onclick='return downloadFiles()'>{{$employee['image']}}</a>
```

JS:

```
function downloadFiles(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    for (img of IMAGES_FROM_THE_BACK) { 
        setTimeout(() => {
            window.open(`/people/employees/download/${img}`);
        }, 300);
    }
});
```

Please note that you would need to pass your images to an array or object from the back to the front end where you've your HTML.

Comment: Ok, can I make a zip folder with a link@jguarate

Comment: Yes, sure you can use the same download route (/people/employees/download/) -> (public function download($image){) and change your method implementation like it is explained on the https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1754352/download-multiple-files-as-a-zip-file-using-php answer. You just need to use the PHP ZipClass file. E.g: `new \ZipArchive();`

Comment: Zipping is the way to go here, @JGuarate maybe you can propose another answer?

Comment: Yeap. Like I said, Zipping or a front-end implementation to trigger the browser with multiple downloads whatever suits your business needs better. Oh, and If the seconds one considers that multiple browsers with prompt the user for permissions to download multiple files.

Answer (score 0):

As the subop from above said It's impossible, because HTTP doesn't support multiple files download. And one of solution is to open connection per file to download, but in my opinion more elegant would be files zipping which has them all.

PHP provides solution for that and it's **[ZipArchive](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.ziparchive.php)**

After, you ZIP all files, write on disk in tmp directory, and send a stream response using your file location. After php close connection, you can use *Laravel Terminate Middleware/Callback* and delete that archive to flush space on your disk.

Simple example in plain PHP taken from link above.

```php
$files = array('image.jpeg','text.txt','music.wav');
$zipname = 'enter_any_name_for_the_zipped_file.zip';
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$zip->open($zipname, ZipArchive::CREATE);
foreach ($files as $file) {
  $zip->addFile($file);
}
$zip->close();

///Then download the zipped file.
header('Content-Type: application/zip');
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename='.$zipname);
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($zipname));
readfile($zipname);
```