# Downloading multiple PDF files in Laravel

Tags: laravel, pdf, download

I'm tring to download multiple PDFs using this method:

```
public function download(){
    $documents = Documents::all();
    foreach ($documents as $document) {
        response()->download(public_path("/uploads/documents/".$document->filename));
    }

    return 1;
}
```

This works, but only downloads one file. The other files aren't downloaded. Why?

Comment: `response()->download()` triggers a download and exits the current code. If you want to download multiple files, you'll likely need to combine them first, i.e. into a `.zip` file or similar.

Comment: You can use like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36675505/laravel-5-multiple-download-file

Comment: you can use laravel jobs for download many files without zip