# Creating a link that will allow anyone with the link to download a file

Tags: php

I'm trying to create a link that will allow anyone with the link to download a file.

I'm trying this with PHP pure and CodeIgniter, but the link never gets created. I'm wondering where I should store the file, in the documents or in the database?

Thanks.

Comment: Your question is completely vague.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store your file in a Server folder rather in Database. Try with below snippet to force download the file. It means, You'll get a Download dialogue window even if file formats (Like Images, PDF etc.) could be opened within the Browser.

HTML

```
 <a href="download.php">Download File</a>
```

download.php

```
<?php
    $yourFile = "Your_Folder/YOUR_File.ext";
    header('Content-Type: application/download');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$yourFile);
    header("Content-Length: " . filesize($yourFile));

    $fp = fopen($yourFile, "r");
    fpassthru($fp);
    fclose($fp);
?>
```

Comment: You can Combine all files & Create Zip on the fly. Follow : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1754352/download-multiple-files-as-zip-in-php

Comment: Thanks a lot for your guidance

Comment: I'm actually new in stackoverflow.com, from where i can and should click acceptation button, i couldn't find.

Comment: @NangialaiStoman When hovering mouse under Votes, You can see a tick mark like this URL http://i.stack.imgur.com/LkiIZ.png