# Download more then one file at the same time

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a button and if I click on that button then there are more than one html file store in folder should be show matched with database.

My code are:

```
<?php
include("connection.php");
extract($_REQUEST);

 $query=mysql_query("select * from fad_record where t_id='$word'") or die(mysql_error());
while($result=mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
extract($result);
        ob_start();
        include("3_day_notice_fad/$fad_html_name");
        $html_content = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();
        echo $html_content;
}
?>
```

But when code runs then all files are showing in one file. But I want all different file open in different tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This cannot be done using only PHP, opening tabs is a browser option so you need a client side script. jQuery can do that. You should start by creating an ajax call to the PHP and open the result in a new tab. Although, users with spam blockers or with a high-security setting will block that. I would advise against such a feature and find a better way to do this. Perhaps use the jquery UI tab system?

https://jqueryui.com/tabs/

Take a look at it and see if you can use that in your logic

---

Convert HTML to PDF

[DOMPDF](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf) : php class that wraps the html and builds the pdf. Works good, customizable (if you know php), based on pdflib, if I remember right it takes even some CSS. Bad news: slow when the html is big or complex.

[HTML2PS](http://www.tufat.com/s_html2ps_html2pdf.htm): same as DOMPDF, but this one converts first to a .ps (ghostscript) file, then, to whatever format you need (pdf, jpg, png). For me is little better than dompdf, but has the same *speed problem*.. but, better compatibility with CSS.

Those two are php classes, but if you can install some software on the server, and access it throught passthru() or system(), give a look to these too:

[wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/): based on webkit (safari's wrapper), is really fast and powerful.. seems like  this is the best one (atm) for converting html pages to pdf on the fly; taking only 2 seconds for a 3 page xHTML document with CSS2. It is a recent project, anyway, the google.code page is often updated.

[htmldoc](https://www.msweet.org/projects.php?Z1) : This one is a tank, it never really stops/crashes.. the project looks dead since 2007, but anyway if you don't need CSS compatibility this can be nice for you.

Comment: You cannot send more than 1 file in response to an HTTP request. What I would suggest is zip the file in a single file and return that. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1754352/download-multiple-files-as-zip-in-php

Comment: Basically I have some html file and I have to convert them into pdf  and then download. But don't know, how to convert html file into pdf. So I added javascript print() in html file, so that if html file opens in browser then click on button, I can save them in pdf. But it works with single html. But if you please tell me process of convert html to pdf then I can save them in zip file.

Comment: Will post a new answer for this one. Please edit your question with how to convert HTML to PDF so I am not off topic lol

Comment: Made an edit instead ;-) There's also a few online API on google but they're not free. Best to use a GPL library. I used wkhtmltopdf on one of my projects but you need server privileges to get it working.