# Yii2 - Multiples files download from Folder

Tags: php, pdf, yii2

I have a issue with Yii2 and multiple download.
I'm using Fpdf to generate PDF and save them on a folder. This is ok, but when I try to download all of them from that folder, he just return me one file, the first one:

```
 for($x = 1; $x <= $vlt; $x++){
        if (file_exists($tempPath.'Client'.$x.'.pdf')) {
            Yii::$app->response->sendFile($tempPath.'Client'.$x.'.pdf');
        }
    }
```

I don´t understand why this happen.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

This aint happening friend, You should zip all files and then download them rather than trying to download them like this [**`SEE WHY`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1754352/download-multiple-files-as-a-zip-file-using-php).

You should instead zip and download all the files, you can use [**`ZipArchive`**](http://php.net/manual/en/class.ziparchive.php) class to achieve this, change your above code so that all your zip files are added into a single ZIP and then download that zip file.

Just remember that

**1)** The below script uses a temp folder inside your project root with the name `tmp` to create the zip file and download, adjust your path accordingly for `$zipname` if you want to use some other directory.

**2)** You should provide the complete path in the `$tempPath` so that the files are added successfully to the zip file.

```
    //set zip file name for download
    $zipFilename = md5('file-' . time()) . '.zip';

    //zip file name with path
    $zipPath = Yii::$app->basePath . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '..' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'tmp' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $zipFilename;

    //start adding the files into the zip archive
    $zip = new \ZipArchive();

    //open zip archive 
    $zip->open($zipPath, \ZipArchive::CREATE | ZipArchive::OVERWRITE);

    for ($x = 1; $x <= $vlt; $x++) {
        if (file_exists($tempPath . 'Client' . $x . '.pdf')) {
            $zip->addFile(realpath($tempPath . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'Client' . $x . '.pdf'), 'Client' . $x . '.pdf');
        }
    }
    

    //close the zip file
    $zip->close();

    //return zip archive name without path
    Yii::$app->response->sendFile($zipPath);
```

Comment: The client dont want zip files. What I think to do, is put all of files inside one PDF only, and download a single PDF.

This project is to old people, mostly dont know what is zip files.

Comment: Ok , if that sorts out your problem

Comment: Great solution, works perfectly after integrating it with my app needs!

Comment: @DiegoTejada glad it helped you out