# php - generate and download multiple file

Tags: php, header, fpdf

i'm using php and the need is to generate a pdf (i'm using fpdf) and an xml file with the same content.
The pdf / xml is called by an html form with post parameter.
Unfortunately gets downloaded only one page (pdf or xml). How can i solve the problem?

## form page

```
<form name="aaa" id="aaa" action="page1.php" method="POST" target="_blank">
        ....
        <div><input type="submit" value="Insert"></div>
</form>
```

## page1

```
<?php
    //do stuff and generate pdf
    header("Location: page2.php");
?>
```

## page2

```
<?php
        //do same stuff above and generate xml
        header("Cache-Control: public");
        header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=test.xml");
        header("Content-Type: text/xml");
        header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
        ...
    ?>
```

i'd like on the form submission that both pdf and xml gets download

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately that's not directly possible in one call. 
Each HTTP response can return for example one response, one file or a redirect.

Possible solutions:

- Combine both files in a zip Archiv [Download multiple files as a zip-file using php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1754352/download-multiple-files-as-a-zip-file-using-php)
- Print out 2 IFrames - the `src` is a page returning a file (kind of your `page2`) - one iframe taget returns the xml the other pdf